# Can ZFC prove having a proper class of stages of the cumulative hierarchy that are equal in size to their ordinal index?

Tags: set-theory

Can ZFC prove: $$\forall x \exists \kappa: x \in V_\kappa \land |V_\kappa|=\kappa$$

Where $V_\kappa$ is a stage of the cumulative hierarchy defined in the customary manner.

Comment: Yes, if $\kappa$ is a beth fixed point. You can show that there is a proper class of beth fixed point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily check that (almost follows from by definition!) $|V_{\omega+\alpha}|=\beth_\alpha$, where $\beth_\alpha$ is the $\alpha$th [beth number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_number). You can also see that $\alpha\le\beth_\alpha$ as $\alpha\mapsto \beth_\alpha$ is increasing.

Let $\alpha>\omega$. Consider $\kappa_0=\beth_\alpha$, $\kappa_{n+1}=\beth_{\kappa_n}$ and $\kappa_\omega = \sup_n\kappa_n$. You can see that $\alpha\le \kappa_\omega$ and $\beth_{\kappa_\omega}=\kappa_\omega$. Especially, $|V_{\kappa_\omega}|=\kappa_\omega$, and $V_\alpha\subseteq V_{\kappa_\omega}$. Hence every set is a member of some $V_\kappa$ such that $|V_\kappa|=\kappa$.